# Editing Facebook Like-Box Css on The FLy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook

I am not a coder but, i am able to get my way around code most of the time. However, i found that this is the best place to ask questions relating to code stuff.

I have been working on a website for a client and i am at 95% - the only problem i have is facebook like-box. i have found several tutorials on the web to modify the like box css, and i have implemented most of the recommendations but, i have no favorable results.

Please - stackoverflow help!

I know jquery/javascript is a very powerful language. And facebook like uses javascript iframe/xfbml.

what code would you use, if you were to modify the like box css elements before loading them .

I say load cos i am loading my like box via ".load" ajax. So, when a user clicks the facebook button jquery loads it.

In short: how would i edit a css file on the fly, and then load the edited version afterwards.

thanks

Comment: JayJay, I'm afraid your question is far too vague. To get a reasonable response try showing the relevant HTM, Javascript and CSS (e.g. by putting it on jsfiddle.net). You wouldn't necessarily edit the CSS file, but the CSS for the relevant element.

Comment: naming the likebox iframe with id or class, then manipulate it with jquery ;) seems it's nice idea...

Answer (score 4):

The key problem that you'll have here is that FB's Like button is loaded inside an iframe - a self-contained HTML document within your page (if you use firebug or webkit inspector to inspect the like button, you'll see it's within `<body>`, `<html>`, then `<iframe>`).

The thing about these self-contained pages is that you can't access or manipulate them from the surrounding document (your page). You can change the 'src' attribute (telling the iframe to load a new page), but you can't apply or change styles on the elements inside the page. This is a security limitation that browsers have.

I know that it is possible to have a custom-styled like button, but I don't think it's done with the iframe method.

Comment: Bingo.  Due to cross-domain restrictions, you simply can't get at the elements inside an iFrame.  It's just a no-go.  You'll have to either build your own Like button (which may or may not be possible) or go through Facebook proper.